# Filtering the results on a UICollectionview in Swift 3 not working?

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

First loading with itemlist is working fine but after filter the collection view is not updating. I have added a search bar and trying to filter the result but UICollectionview failed to update view.

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
//itemlist
var itemList = [item1, item2, item3, item4,..] 

//configured searchbar

func viewDidLoad() {
      self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
      self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
      self.definesPresentationContext = true
      self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Items"
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.prominent
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if resultSearchController.isActive {
            return filterSearch.count
      }
      return itemList.count
      }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      var item = itemList()
      if resultSearchController.isActive {
            item = filterSearch[indexPath.row]
      } else {
            item = itemList[indexPath.row]
      }
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
      cell.titleLabel.text = item
      return cell
}
```

//filtering the items into filterSearch but collection view is not updating according to filter.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
       filterSearch = itemList.filter { itemList  in
            return temList.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
      }
      self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code about " storeList " in your code?

Comment: through debug I saw that searchcontroller is not showing active although it is active. Can you please suggest me about the mistake I made?@PhaniSai

Comment: Your code looks okay however  You can check on "resultSearchController.isActive"  when it is return  "true"

Comment: On activating editing the resultSearchController.isActive is returning "true" but while editing it's returning false. can you explain please? @PhaniSai

Comment: I just updated answer has a look on changes

Comment: in which part of the code did you add the searchcontroller to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Check bellow change in your code

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
//itemlist
var itemList = [item1, item2, item3, item4,..] 

//configured searchbar
var issearchactive:Bool = false

func viewDidLoad() {
      self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
      self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
      self.definesPresentationContext = true
      self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Items"
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.prominent
      self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if issearchactive {
            return filterSearch.count
      }
      return itemList.count
      }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      var item = itemList()
      if issearchactive {
            item = filterSearch[indexPath.row]
      } else {
            item = itemList[indexPath.row]
      }
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
      cell.titleLabel.text = item
      return cell
}

    func updateSearchResults(searchText:String) {
           filterSearch = itemList.filter { obj  in
                return obj.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
          }
          self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }


  override func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        issearchactive = true
        return true
    }

  override func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

      updateSearchResults(searchText:textfield.text)

        issearchactive = false

         }

    override func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

  updateSearchResults(searchText:textfield.text)

        return true
    }
```